# Pythonで自作モジュールをimportする

Tags: python

Pythonでプログラムが長くなったので実行部分と関数やデータ部分に分けようと思い、listing.pyというファイルに

```
def alist():
    list1=[hogehoge]
```

とデータを並べ、それをmain.pyで

```
import listing
listing.alist()
```

としましたが、エラー

```
NameError: name 'list1' is not defined
```

となり、list1に代入されません。
defの中でglobal list1とやってもだめでした。

どのように対処すべきでしょうか。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラーは`list1`ではなく`list11`となっているようですが、それはここでのタイポなだけですか？

Comment: すいません。タイポです。修正いたしました。

Comment: 質問文に示されているプログラムだけではエラーを再現できないのですが、`main.py` のプログラムはこれだけではないのではないでしょうか。具体的には、`main.py` で `list1` を参照しようとしていませんか？　エラーを再現できるような例にしてみてください。

Comment: 回答になりませんが
pythonは、エラーメッセージが適切だった印象があります。
エラーの通りのことが起きているはずです。

Comment: 返信遅くなりすいません。ご回答ありがとうございます。まさに`main.py`で`list1`を参照したいと考えています。不可能なのでしょうか。

Comment: エラー本文以外にもスタックトレース（関数の呼び出し、それぞれのファイルや行数が記載されているもの）を一緒に記載してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

回答末尾のサンプルコードの項番1.と3.でエラーが発生します。
おそらく項番1.のようなコードを実行してエラーになっているのではないでしょうか。

簡単に解説しますと、[import したモジュールの global 変数にアクセスする方法](https://qiita.com/sutoh/items/bce50207d1f05e6a52df)のようにpythonのグローバル変数は完全にグローバルではありません。
importしたモジュール内で宣言された変数にアクセスする場合は、`{モジュール名}.{変数名}`でアクセスする必要があります。(項番2.)

もしくは関数の戻り値を`return`で返して変数に渡すのが正当な解決方法です。(項番4.)
変数のスコープはけっこうハマりやすい罠になります。私も回答のために調べてみて勉強になりました。

下記のサンプルコードはpython 3.xのみで動作します。
また、`listing.py`が既に存在する場合、上書きします。
ご承知おきください。

```
with open('listing.py', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write("""# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def alist():
    global list1
    list1 = [ 'hoge', 'fuga', 'piyo' ]

def blist():
    global list2
    list2 = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ]
    return list2
""")

import sys
import listing

listing.alist()
# 1. importしたモジュール内変数には直接アクセスできない
try:
    print(list1)
except NameError as e:
    print(e.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2]))
# 2. モジュール内変数としてglobalにアクセスできる
print(listing.list1)

# 3. 戻り値を受け取らないので動かない
listing.blist()
# 4. 戻り値を受け取るので動く(コメントアウトしてエラーを誘発中)
#list2 = listing.blist()

try:
    print(list2)
except NameError as e:
    print(e.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2]))
```

Comment: どうやらうまく行ったようです。ありがとうございました。
一点お聞きしたいのですが、print(listing.blist)としたときに(alistでも同じですが）
<function blist at 0x000001D69B9D9F28>のように出るのは一体何なのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントで頂いたご質問につきましては、[別の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/9820)を作成して回答しました。詳細はそちらをご参照ください。

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。ググってもヒットしなかったので非常に勉強になりました。