# 関数に括弧を付けずprintすると<function hoge at 0x が表示される理由

Tags: python, python3

`def hoge()`を定義した時に、`print(hoge())`を実行すると正常な結果が取得できます。
しかし関数名のみを指定して`print(hoge)`を実行すると`<function hoge at 0x...>`が表示されるのは何故でしょうか。

```
def hoge():
    return "foo" 

print(hoge())  #foo
print(hoge)    #<function hoge at 0x...>
```

※これはpythonに関する回答への[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/53927)で頂いた質問に加筆修正したものです。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

実行結果は正常です。
`print(hoge)`のように関数に括弧をつけず実行すると、**関数オブジェクト**の[識別子](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#id)を[表示します](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098556)。

関数名は[特殊属性](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__name__#definition.__name__)として、識別子は組み込み関数`id()`で取得できます。
すなわち `"<function {0} at {1}>".format(hoge.__name__, hex(id(hoge)))` で質問の表示内容を再現できます。

この機能の何が嬉しいのかというと、関数自体を別の関数や配列に代入できることです。
ともあれ定義済みの関数名を`print`するとエラーにならず、関数自体を識別する一意の値が返ります。
括弧を付けないと関数の中身は**実行されない**のでご注意ください。

```
def hoge():
    return "foo" 

print(hoge())  #foo
print(hoge)    #<function hoge at 0x...>
print("<function {0} at 0x{1:X}>".format(hoge.__name__, id(hoge))) #同上(ただしHEXの前ゼロは消える)

fuga = hoge
print(fuga())  #foo

ppp = [ hoge, hoge, hoge ]
for piyo in ppp:
    print(piyo()) #foo foo foo

i = 0
def add():
    global i
    i += 1

print(i) #0
add()
print(i) #1
add
print(i) #1 ※値が加算されていない
```