# x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10000,) and (1,)のエラーの解決

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10000,) and (1,)のエラーの解決
要素数がなぜ変化しているのかがわからない

```py
from scipy.special import kv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import math
from math import gamma
from sympy import *
import os

xs=np.logspace(-4, 2, 10000)
ys=np.logspace(0, 5, 10000)
vs=np.logspace(0,5,10000)

m=9.10938356*1e-31
c=2.99792458*1e+8
q=1.6021766208*1e-19
pa=np.pi/2#ピッチ角#
sin_pa=math.sin(pa)
B1=100*1e-6*1e-4
a = gamma(1/3)
def v_c(y):
    return 3*y**2*q*B1*sin_pa/(4*np.pi*m*c)

f = lambda z: kv(5/3,z)
F = [quad(f,x,np.inf)[0]*x for x in xs]
G = [(4*np.pi/np.sqrt(3)/a)*(x/2)**(1/3) for x in xs]
H = [((np.pi/2)**(1/2))*(x**(1/2))*(np.exp(-x))for x in xs]

def A(x,y,F,G,H):
    if x <= 5.0*1e-3:
        return G(x,y)
    elif 5.0*1e-3 < x < 30:
        return F(x,y)
    elif 30 <= x:
        return H(x,y)
    
vec_A = np.vectorize(A)
def L(x,y):
    return vec_A(xs,ys,F,G,H)

def P(v,y):
    x=v/v_c
    return (math.sqrt(3)*q**3*B1*sin_pa/(m*c**2))*L(v/v_c)

gmin=1
gmax=10**5
N=10
p=-2

def R(v,y):
    return N*y**-p*P

def Pt(v):
    return [quad(lambda y:R, gmin, gmax)[0] for y in ys]


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.grid
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log') 
ax.plot(vs,Pt)

plt.show()
```

エラー

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-33ed3b99f09b> in <module>
     60 ax.set_yscale('log')
     61 ax.set_xscale('log')
---> 62 ax.plot(vs,Pt)
     63 
     64 plt.show()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1663         """
   1664         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D._alias_map)
-> 1665         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1666         for line in lines:
   1667             self.add_line(line)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    223                 this += args[0],
    224                 args = args[1:]
--> 225             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    226 
    227     def get_next_color(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    389             x, y = index_of(tup[-1])
    390 
--> 391         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    392 
    393         if self.command == 'plot':

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    268         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
    269             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension, but "
--> 270                              "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
    271         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    272             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have "

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10000,) and (1,)
```

追記

```
from scipy.special import kv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np
import math
from math import gamma
from sympy import *
import os

x=np.logspace(-4, 2, 10000)
xs=np.logspace(-4, 2, 10000)
v=np.logspace(-4, 2, 10000)


m=9.10938356*1e-31
c=2.99792458*1e+8
q=1.6021766208*1e-19
pa=np.pi/2
sin_pa=math.sin(pa)
B1=100*1e-6*1e-4
a = gamma(1/3)

f = lambda z: kv(5/3,z)
F = [quad(f,x,np.inf)[0]*x for x in xs]
G = [(4*np.pi/np.sqrt(3)/a)*(x/2)**(1/3) for x in xs]
H = [((np.pi/2)**(1/2))*(x**(1/2))*(np.exp(-x))for x in xs]

def A(x,F,G,H):
    if x <= 5.0*1e-3:
        return G
    elif 5.0*1e-3 < x < 30:
        return F
    elif 30 <= x:
        return H
    
vec_A = np.vectorize(A)
L=vec_A(xs,F,G,H)

P=(math.sqrt(3)*q**3*B1*sin_pa/(m*c**2))*L

gmin=1
gmax=10**5
N=10/(10**5-1)
p=-2

s[0]=L*x**(-1/2)

def x1(v):
    return 4*np.pi*m*c*v/(3*q*B1*sin_pa*gmin**2)
def x2(v):
    return 4*np.pi*m*c*v/(3*q*B1*sin_pa*gmax**2)


b1=-1/np.sqrt(v)
b2=(np.sqrt(3)*q**3*B1*sin_pa/(2*m*c**2))
b3=np.sqrt(3*q*B1*sin_pa/(4*np.pi*m*c))
b=b1*b2*b3*N

Pt=[quad(s,4*np.pi*m*c*v/(3*q*B1*sin_pa*1**2),4*np.pi*m*c*v/(3*q*B1*sin_pa*(10**5)**2))[0]*b for x in xs]

vec_B = np.vectorize(Pt)
Ptot=vec_B(v)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(xs,Ptot)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6fbdeb4f340e> in <module>
     58 b=b1*b2*b3*N
     59 
---> 60 Pt=[quad(s,4*np.pi*m*c*v/(3*q*B1*sin_pa*1**2),4*np.pi*m*c*v/(3*q*B1*sin_pa*(10**5)**2))[0]*b for x in xs]
     61 
     62 vec_B = np.vectorize(Pt)

<ipython-input-14-6fbdeb4f340e> in <listcomp>(.0)
     58 b=b1*b2*b3*N
     59 
---> 60 Pt=[quad(s,4*np.pi*m*c*v/(3*q*B1*sin_pa*1**2),4*np.pi*m*c*v/(3*q*B1*sin_pa*(10**5)**2))[0]*b for x in xs]
     61 
     62 vec_B = np.vectorize(Pt)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    336 
    337     # check the limits of integration: \int_a^b, expect a < b
--> 338     flip, a, b = b < a, min(a, b), max(a, b)
    339 
    340     if weight is None:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: エラーは、"ax.plot(vs,Pt)"から始まった動作で起きているのですから、まずは２つの引数(vsとPt)が何で、それが適切なのかどうかを確認するところからデバッグを始めてはいかがでしょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print(Pt)`の戻り値は`<function Pt at 0x01234567>`のように[関数オブジェクトの識別子](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/54013)が1つだけ返ります。

つまり1次元の1個の値が返ってくるので`vs`の配列と次元数が合わずにエラーとなります。(`ax.plot`は高階関数ではないので、引数に関数を渡して自動的に戻り値を展開する機能はありません)

エラーにならないためにはPtの戻り値を渡してあげる必要がありますが、関数Ptもこのままでは下記のエラーが発生します。
`TypeError: must be real number, not function`

なので関数Ptを直してエラーを解消します。
`return [quad(lambda y:R(v, y), gmin, gmax)[0] for y in ys]`

すると関数Rでエラーが発生します。
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'`
関数Rから呼び出している関数Pに引数がないことが原因です。

それを直すと関数Pで同様のエラーが発生します。
関数v_cと関数Lの引数が足りません。(関数Lの内部では引数x,yが使われずにxs,ysを使っていますが、意図通りのコードでしょうか)
次に関数Aでエラーが発生します。変数F,G,Hは関数ではないので引数を渡せません。
これらを全てクリアしても修正後の関数Ptでエラーが発生します。
`R(v, y)`の次元数が多いので`R(v, y)[0]`などで次元数を減らす対応が必要です。

変数と関数の使い方が少しあやふやになってしまっているようです。
個々の関数を分けて動かしてみてください。
動作を確認しながらデバッグしてそれぞれの関数の意味と要素数を見直す方が、問題を解決する近道になるかもしれません。

Comment: ご助言通り、各関数を調べたところ、Pt以外は修正可能でしたがPtにおいてエラーValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()が起こっている状態です。　また、R(v,y)についてですが、コードの通りであれば積分によって次元数が減ると思っていたのですが違うのでしょうか？